# innerHTML examples work well until I incorporate them into other Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, innerhtml

I experiment successfully with W3Schools examples of using innerHTML, such as https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_elements
My goal is to read and write form control displayed values to/from JavaScript code when I invoke "onclick"s.

But when I simply place an example in an appropriate spot in an existing PHP script, nothing appears on the webpage when I click the "Try It" button.  Granted, the existing code has its own form, other Javascript functions and references to $_POST values.

Here is an excerpt of my PHP script, including the example "Donald Duck" code.  Note, neither myFunction() nor myFunction2() produced any screen change when invoked.  Nor did a version that used document.write(x)

```
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
...

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("rmOne");
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

function myFunction2() {
  $_POST.forEach(output)
}

function output(element, index, array) {
  document.write(index + element + "<br>")
}
</script>

</head>
<body>


<form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="Donald"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the first element in the form.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<?php

require_once "config.azsb.php";
require_once "functionsarrays.azsb.php";

if ( isset( $_POST["roomSel"] ) )
  $room = $_POST["roomSel"];
```

Appreciations in advance!

Comment: Wait, you are trying to reach a php variable in javascript? Please take a look at [the differences between client and server side programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171210/153671).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("rmOne");
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

function myFunction2() {
  <?php
  foreach($_POST as $index => $element):
  ?>
  output(<?= $index ?>, '<?= $element ?>');
  <?php endforeach; ?>
}

function output(element, index, array) {
  document.write(index + element + "<br>")
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the improved code.  Sadly, although these work when submitted as separate programs, but when integrated into my existing code, nothing changes on the screen.  These aren't the actual functions I will produce, but they perform a skeleton of what I want.  Then I'll extrapolate.

Comment: I put DazZDylz's version of "myFunction()" into the Donald Duck example (from W3Schools) and it works.  I also changed the button definition to  
   <input type="button" onclick="javascript:myFunction()" value="Try it" />
and that worked, too.  However, the original style button
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
, when put it into my "problem" php code resulted in a call to the form "action" page (not written) rather than myFunction() !!!???.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a PHP variable in JavaScript, because JavaScript get's executed at the client while PHP get's executet on the server.

You can, however, just print the PHP variable into the JavaScript, similar to this:

```
var myVar = <?php echo $yourPhpVariable; ?>;
```

Comment: That's clever!   Thanks.  In the "Donald Duck" example (from W3schools) data is exchanged between JavaScript variables and form control value properties, both ways

Comment: ShuntHacks' answer got me thinking. Thanks again.  When the innerHTML property is invoked (in the W3Schools example). how much of the webpage is resent from the server to the browser?  Refresh of the whole page, or just the new part of the document object?

Answer (score 0):

Time out.  I was trying to open two forms on the webpage. Changing to just one changed the nature of the response. Now a try-it click tries to go to the "action" link (subsequent webpage) erroneously (it doesn't exist, yet, nor is that intended for that click.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Closer, but not there yet, despite incorporating suggestions.  The JavaScript myFunction(), supposedly called "onclick" still has no effect on the displayed page (as does the originally cited example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_elements).  I doctored my php code to run by itself (no $_POST dependencies and no MySQL access -- all such data internally defined) so that it can be run by anybody, so please try.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AZ Science Bowl  --  Scorekeeper in Competition Rooms</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.cenx {text-align: center;}
.wfd {width: 100%}
img {padding: 24pt;}
body {background-color: #aacc44; padding: 2%; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}
-->
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function leftPenalty(){
alert("leftPenalty");
var oFormObject = document.forms['rmOne'];
alert('value=' + oFormObject.elements["LeftPenalty"]);
if ( oFormObject.elements["LeftPenalty"] == "4" ) {
  oFormObject.elements("LeftPenalty").value = "";
else
  oFormObject.elements("LeftPenalty").value = "4";
}


function leftToss(){
alert("leftToss");
alert('value=' + document.elements["LeftToss"]);
if ( document.elements["LeftToss"] == "4" ) {
  document.getElementById("LeftToss").innerHTML = "";
else
  document.getElementById("LeftToss").innerHTML = "4";
}

function leftBonus(){
alert("leftBonus");
var x = document.getElementById("mOne").elements[5].value;
alert('value=' + x);
if ( document.elements["LeftBonus"] == "10" ) {
  document.getElementById("LeftBonus").innerHTML = "";
else
  document.getElementById("LeftBonus").innerHTML = "10";
}



function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("rmOne");
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

function myFunction2() {
  <?php
  foreach($_POST as $index => $element):
  ?>
  output(<?= $index ?>, '<?= $element ?>');
  <?php endforeach; ?>
}

function output(element, index, array) {
  document.write(index + element + "<br>")
}
</script>

</head>
<body>



<?php

//require_once "config.azsb.php";
//require_once "functionsarrays.azsb.php";

$NUM_ROUND_EVENTS=7;
$NUM_WAVE_FILES=17;
$MAX_ROOMS=9;
$NUM_ROOM_SCORES_COLS=12;
$MAX_ROUNDS=16;
$NUM_QUESTIONS_PER_ROUND_MAX=25;
$ROOM_SCORES_SKEL="Rm####Scores";

$room = 'Badd';
$round = 'RR1';
$quesNum = '05';

//echo 'Rm, Rnd, Ques = ' . $room . ', ' . $round . ', ' . $quesNum;

//Define an array of printed column names
$scoresTitlesPrinted = array ('Ques #','Penalty','TossUp','Bonus','Sum','Total','Penalty','TossUp','Bonus','Sum','Total');
//Define a sub array to hold the name of each column of DB Table Rm####Scores
$scoresCols =           array ("RR_DE_PK1",    "QuesNumPK2",   "LeftPenalty",   "LeftToss",   "LeftBonus",   "LeftQuesSum",   "LeftRunTot",   "RightPenalty",    "RightToss",   "RightBonus",   "RightQuesSum",   "RightRunTot");
//Define an internal array to hold all values for a given Room and Round Scores
$scoresArray = array (
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"RR1","QuesNumPK2"=>1,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>1,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>1,"LeftRunTot"=>1,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"RR1","QuesNumPK2"=>2,"LeftPenalty"=>4,"LeftToss"=>2,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>6,"LeftRunTot"=>7,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>4,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>4,"RightRunTot"=>4),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"RR1","QuesNumPK2"=>3,"LeftPenalty"=>4,"LeftToss"=>3,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>4,"RightBonus"=>10,"RightQuesSum"=>14,"RightRunTot"=>18),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"RR1","QuesNumPK2"=>4,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>4,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>18),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"RR1","QuesNumPK2"=>5,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>5,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>18),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0)
                     );

$namesRow = array( "LeftTeamLetter"=>"B", "LeftTeamName"=>"Team L in 0203", "RightTeamLetter"=>"D", "RightTeamName"=>"Team R in 0203"   );


//Create a string of $count 'non-break html spaces' (where $count is between 0 and 100)
function htmlSpaces ($count) {
  $strSp = '';
  if ($count > 0 && $count <=100)
    for ($idx=0; $idx<$count; $idx++)
      $strSp .= '&nbsp;';
  return $strSp;
}

/*

//Build a MySQL Table name (Rm####Scores) from a 4-digit-left-0-filled room number of 4-char room name
function roomScoresTableName ($room) {
  return substr_replace ("Rm####Scores", $room, 2, -6);
}

//Build SQL Query string for Team Scores from table Rm####Scores
function buildSQLstringScores ($room, $round, $quesNum) {
  return 'SELECT RR_DE_PK1, QuesNumPK2, LeftPenalty, LeftToss, LeftBonus, (LeftPenalty+LeftToss+LeftBonus) as LeftQuesSum, 0 as LeftRunTot, RightPenalty, RightToss, RightBonus, (RightPenalty+RightToss+RightBonus) as RightQuesSum, 0 as RightRunTot from ' . roomScoresTableName($room) . ' where RR_DE_PK1 = "' . $round . '" and QuesNumPK2<=' . sprintf('%02u',$quesNum) . ' order by QuesNumPK2 limit 25';
}

//Build SQL Query string for Team Letters and Names from table Rm####Scores
function buildSQLstringNames ($room, $round, $quesNum) {
  return 'SELECT LeftTeamLetter, LeftTeamName, RightTeamLetter, RightTeamName from ' . roomScoresTableName($room) . ' where RR_DE_PK1 = "' . $round . '" and QuesNumPK2="01" limit 1';
}

try {
  $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
  $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch ( PDOException $e ) {
  echo DB_DSM . "Database Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
try {
//While processing Room Scores MySQL table Rm####Scores one row at a time, transfer each row to $scoresArray and accumulate Running totals for both Left and Right teams from start of Round until current question.   Then display in reverse order of questions.
  $idr = 0;
  $sqlScores = buildSQLstringScores ($room, $round, $quesNum);
//echo '<p> $sqlScores=' . $sqlScores . '</p>';
//echo '<p> $scoresCols Size=' . count($scoresCols) . '</p>';
//  print_r ( $scoresCols );
//  echo '</pre>';
  $scoresRows = $conn->query( $sqlScores );
//Xfer Scores values to local array (one row at a time), note: left and right Question sums and Runing Totals (set = 0) are calculated as such by Select statement processed by MySQL
  foreach ( $scoresRows as $scoresRow ) {
//  echo '<h4>Scores Row #' . (string)$idr . ':</h4><pre>';
//  print_r ( $scoresRow );
//  echo '</pre>';
    for ($idc=0; $idc<(count($scoresCols)); $idc++) {
      $scoresArray[$idr][$scoresCols[$idc]] = $scoresRow[$scoresCols[$idc]];

//    echo '<br> $idr=' . $idr . ', $idc=' . $idc . ', $ScoresCols[$idc]=' . $scoresCols[$idc] . ', $scoresArray[$idr][$scoresCols[$idc]] =' . $scoresArray[$idr][$scoresCols[$idc]] ;
      if ($idr == 0){
        $scoresArray[$idr]["LeftRunTot"] = $scoresRow["LeftQuesSum"];
        $scoresArray[$idr]["RightRunTot"] = $scoresRow["RightQuesSum"];
      }
      else
      {
        $scoresArray[$idr]["LeftRunTot"] = $scoresRow["LeftQuesSum"] + $scoresArray[$idr-1]["LeftRunTot"];
        $scoresArray[$idr]["RightRunTot"] = $scoresRow["RightQuesSum"] + $scoresArray[$idr-1]["RightRunTot"];
      }
    }
    $idr++;
  }
//  echo '<h4>Scores Array:</h4><pre>';
//  print_r ( $scoresArray );
//  echo '</pre>';
}
catch ( PDOException $e ) {
  echo "Room Scores Query failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

*/


//echo '<h4>Scores Row #' . (string)$idr . ':</h4><pre>';
//print_r ( $scoresArray );
//echo '</pre>';

//Print table header
echo '<hd1 align="center"><b>' . htmlSpaces(60) . 'AZ Science Bowl  --Scorekeepers\' Application for Room ' . $room . ' </b></hd1><br>';

/*

$sqlNames = buildSQLstringNames ($room, $round, $quesNum);

try {
  $namesRows = $conn->query( $sqlNames );
  foreach ( $namesRows as $namesRow ) {
*/

    $spacesNeeded = max(0, 65-(2*strlen($namesRow["LeftTeamName"])));
    echo '<br>' . htmlSpaces(24) . 'Left TEAM <b>-"' . $namesRow["LeftTeamLetter"] . '"- "' . $namesRow["LeftTeamName"] . '"</b>' . htmlSpaces($spacesNeeded) .'Right TEAM <b>-"' . $namesRow["RightTeamLetter"] . '"- "' . $namesRow["RightTeamName"] . '"</b>';

/*
  }
}
catch ( PDOException $e ) {
  echo "Names Query failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
*/

echo '<form name="rmOne" id="room" action="scoreingsubmitpagetwo.php"  method="post">';

  echo 'First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="Donald"><br>';
  echo 'Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br>';
//echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';

echo '<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the first element in the form.</p>';

echo '<input type="button" onclick="javascript:myFunction()" value="Try it" />';

echo '<p id="demo"></p>';

  echo '<div style="width: 30em">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="roomSel" id="roomSel" value="' . $room . '>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="roundSel" id="roundSel" value="' . $round . '>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="quesSel" id="quesSel" value="' . $quesNum . '>';

    echo '<span id="LeftPenalty">#</span>';
    echo '<span id="LeftToss">#</span>';
    echo '<span id="LeftBonus">#</span>';
    echo '<label for="clickLeftPenalty">Penalty</label>';
    echo '<label for="clickLeftToss">Toss</label>';
    echo '<label for="clickLeftBonus">Bonus</label>';
    echo '<br><input type="button" name="clickLeftPenalty" id="clickLeftPenalty" value="+4 / 0" onclick="javascript:leftPenalty()" />';
    echo '<input type="button" name="clickLeftToss" id="clickLeftToss" value="+4 / 0" onclick="javascript:leftToss()" />';
    echo '<input type="button" name="clickLeftBonus" id="clickLeftBonus" value="+10 / 0" onclick="javascript:leftBonus()" />';
echo '</div>';

echo '<table style="width:100%">';
echo '<tr>';
for ($idc=0; $idc<(count($scoresTitlesPrinted)); $idc++) {
  echo '<th align="left">' . $scoresTitlesPrinted[$idc] . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';
//Print rows of question scores in reverse order
for ($idr=$quesNum-1; $idr>=0; $idr--) {
  echo '<tr>';
  for ($idc=1; $idc<(count($scoresCols)); $idc++) {
    if ($scoresArray[$idr][$scoresCols[$idc]] > 0)
      echo '<td align="left"><b>' . $scoresArray[$idr][$scoresCols[$idc]] . '</b></td>';
    else
      echo '<td align="left"> 0 </td>';

  }
  echo '</tr>';
}

$conn = null;
?>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Appreciations, definitely!

Comment: Found a coding error, but no improvement.  Lines 249, 250 & 251 are input type="hidden" and each should end with the following characters:
  . '" />'; instead of . '>';  Just checked the apache error log and nothing was there because of this.  If you do try this code, please make the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note, this remains unresolved:**  The suggestions have been incorporated, yet the W3Schools example code, even when modified with the above suggestions, works by themselves, but when that code is integrated into my (redacted) App code, an alert() at the start of the called Javascript function {myFunction()} doesn't happen (when 'Try it' is clicked).  The subsequent read of or write of data on the page, of course, doesn't happen either.  Below is a chopped version of my code, meaning all of the original MySQL code is removed, instead the resultant data have been directly coded into arrays or constant values, just to make this a demo that I can share.  Debug code has been chopped, too.  Please reference the W3Schools citation above and then try the following.  I obviously need the help.

```
 <!--       AZ Science Bowl Scorekeepers' tablet App Action page ==== Copyright 2017 by Geneous Products  -->
<!--  -->
<!--       This script ScoreingLoginPageZero.php of html, PHP and JavaScript code is called after initial loginto the system and is provided Competition Room ID, Round ID [likely to be retrieved from MySQL dtaserver) and a Question number  -->
<!--  -->
<!--       This script is provided room, round and question data from script ScoreingLoginPageZero.php using form control values in this script and $_POST references in ScoreingActionPageOne.php (which is called by a "Login" Submit control).  -->
<!--       Scorekeeper can click buttons to provisionally points to a Team's score as the questioning progresses. then click a Submit button request a verity page which will write the provisional score values to the DataBase, optionally advance the question number and call this page back up, displaying the updated data and ready to accept new provisional values. -->
<!--  -->
<!--       "Doctored" code for public testing of Scorekeepers' main tablet App  -->
<html>
<head>
<title>AZ Science Bowl  --  Scorekeeper in Competition Rooms</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.cenx {text-align: center;}
.wfd {width: 100%}
img {padding: 24pt;}
body {background-color: #aacc44; padding: 2%; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}
-->
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function leftPenalty(){
alert("leftPenalty");
var oFormObject = document.forms['rmOne'];
alert('value=' + oFormObject.elements["LeftPenalty"]);
if ( oFormObject.elements["LeftPenalty"] == "4" ) {
  oFormObject.elements("LeftPenalty").value = "";
else
  oFormObject.elements("LeftPenalty").value = "4";
}


function leftToss(){
alert("leftToss");
alert('value=' + document.elements["LeftToss"]);
if ( document.elements["LeftToss"] == "4" ) {
  document.getElementById("LeftToss").innerHTML = "";
else
  document.getElementById("LeftToss").innerHTML = "4";
}

function leftBonus(){
alert("leftBonus");
var x = document.getElementById("mOne").elements[5].value;
alert('value=' + x);
if ( document.elements["LeftBonus"] == "10" ) {
  document.getElementById("LeftBonus").innerHTML = "";
else
  document.getElementById("LeftBonus").innerHTML = "10";
}



function myFunction() {
    alert('myFunction called');
    var x = document.getElementById("rmOne");
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

function myFunction2() {
  <?php
  foreach($_POST as $index => $element):
  ?>
  output(<?= $index ?>, '<?= $element ?>');
  <?php endforeach; ?>
}

function output(element, index, array) {
  document.write(index + element + "<br>")
}
</script>

</head>
<body>



<?php


$NUM_ROUND_EVENTS=7;
$NUM_WAVE_FILES=17;
$MAX_ROOMS=9;
$NUM_ROOM_SCORES_COLS=12;
$MAX_ROUNDS=16;
$NUM_QUESTIONS_PER_ROUND_MAX=25;
$ROOM_SCORES_SKEL="Rm####Scores";

$room = 'Badd';
$round = 'RR1';
$quesNum = '05';


//Define an array of printed column names
$scoresTitlesPrinted = array ('Ques #','Penalty','TossUp','Bonus','Sum','Total','Penalty','TossUp','Bonus','Sum','Total');
//Define a sub array to hold the name of each column of DB Table Rm####Scores
$scoresCols =           array ("RR_DE_PK1",    "QuesNumPK2",   "LeftPenalty",   "LeftToss",   "LeftBonus",   "LeftQuesSum",   "LeftRunTot",   "RightPenalty",    "RightToss",   "RightBonus",   "RightQuesSum",   "RightRunTot");
//Define an internal array to hold all values for a given Room and Round Scores
$scoresArray = array (
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"RR1","QuesNumPK2"=>1,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>1,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>1,"LeftRunTot"=>1,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"RR1","QuesNumPK2"=>2,"LeftPenalty"=>4,"LeftToss"=>2,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>6,"LeftRunTot"=>7,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>4,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>4,"RightRunTot"=>4),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"RR1","QuesNumPK2"=>3,"LeftPenalty"=>4,"LeftToss"=>3,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>4,"RightBonus"=>10,"RightQuesSum"=>14,"RightRunTot"=>18),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"RR1","QuesNumPK2"=>4,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>4,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>18),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"RR1","QuesNumPK2"=>5,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>5,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>18),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0),
                        array ("RR_DE_PK1"=>"","QuesNumPK2"=>0,"LeftPenalty"=>0,"LeftToss"=>0,"LeftBonus"=>0,"LeftQuesSum"=>0,"LeftRunTot"=>0,"RightPenalty"=>0, "RightToss"=>0,"RightBonus"=>0,"RightQuesSum"=>0,"RightRunTot"=>0)
                     );

$namesRow = array( "LeftTeamLetter"=>"B", "LeftTeamName"=>"Team L in 0203", "RightTeamLetter"=>"D", "RightTeamName"=>"Team R in 0203"   );


//Create a string of $count 'non-break html spaces' (where $count is between 0 and 100)
function htmlSpaces ($count) {
  $strSp = '';
  if ($count > 0 && $count <=100)
    for ($idx=0; $idx<$count; $idx++)
      $strSp .= '&nbsp;';
  return $strSp;
}


//Print table header
echo '<hd1 align="center"><b>' . htmlSpaces(60) . 'AZ Science Bowl  --Scorekeepers\' Application for Room ' . $room . ' </b></hd1><br>';


    $spacesNeeded = max(0, 65-(2*strlen($namesRow["LeftTeamName"])));
    echo '<br>' . htmlSpaces(24) . 'Left TEAM <b>-"' . $namesRow["LeftTeamLetter"] . '"- "' . $namesRow["LeftTeamName"] . '"</b>' . htmlSpaces($spacesNeeded) .'Right TEAM <b>-"' . $namesRow["RightTeamLetter"] . '"- "' . $namesRow["RightTeamName"] . '"</b>';


echo '<form name="rmOne" id="room" action="scoreingsubmitpagetwo.php"  method="post">';

  echo 'First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="Donald"><br>';
  echo 'Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br>';
//echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';

echo '<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the first element in the form.</p>';

echo '<input type="button" onclick="javascript:myFunction()" value="Try it" />';

echo '<p id="demo"></p>';

  echo '<div style="width: 30em">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="roomSel" id="roomSel" value="' . $room . '" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="roundSel" id="roundSel" value="' . $round . '" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="quesSel" id="quesSel" value="' . $quesNum . '" />';

    echo '<span id="LeftPenalty">#</span>';
    echo '<span id="LeftToss">#</span>';
    echo '<span id="LeftBonus">#</span>';
    echo '<label for="clickLeftPenalty">Penalty</label>';
    echo '<label for="clickLeftToss">Toss</label>';
    echo '<label for="clickLeftBonus">Bonus</label>';
    echo '<br><input type="button" name="clickLeftPenalty" id="clickLeftPenalty" value="+4 / 0" onclick="javascript:leftPenalty()" />';
    echo '<input type="button" name="clickLeftToss" id="clickLeftToss" value="+4 / 0" onclick="javascript:leftToss()" />';
    echo '<input type="button" name="clickLeftBonus" id="clickLeftBonus" value="+10 / 0" onclick="javascript:leftBonus()" />';
echo '</div>';

echo '<table style="width:100%">';
echo '<tr>';
for ($idc=0; $idc<(count($scoresTitlesPrinted)); $idc++) {
  echo '<th align="left">' . $scoresTitlesPrinted[$idc] . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';
//Print rows of question scores in reverse order
for ($idr=$quesNum-1; $idr>=0; $idr--) {
  echo '<tr>';
  for ($idc=1; $idc<(count($scoresCols)); $idc++) {
    if ($scoresArray[$idr][$scoresCols[$idc]] > 0)
      echo '<td align="left"><b>' . $scoresArray[$idr][$scoresCols[$idc]] . '</b></td>';
    else
      echo '<td align="left"> 0 </td>';

  }
  echo '</tr>';
}

$conn = null;
?>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: W3Schools example code is at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_elements

PS: I even tried adding the tail of the above URL to my browser's input line, but no help.  Sigh